# Clarification on proof that orthogonal matrices have $-1$ and $1$ as eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

All orthogonal matrices have an eigenvalue of $1$ and $-1$. The proof provided is as follows.

Let an orthogonal matrix **Q** have eigenvalues $\lambda$.

Then $\mathbf{Qx}=\lambda\mathbf{x}$ and since **Q** is orthogonal,

$\mathbf{Ix}=\mathbf{Q^TQx}=\mathbf{Q^T}(\lambda \mathbf{x}) = \lambda(\mathbf{Q^Tx})=\lambda^2\mathbf{x}$.

Why is $\mathbf{Q^Tx} = \lambda \mathbf{x}$?

Comment: What about $\frac15\pmatrix{4&3\\-3&4}$?

Comment: Or just $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. The eigenvalues are $\pm i$. The proof is wrong and the claim is false.

Comment: In case the other comments are not clear enough, it is not true that the only possible eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix are $1$ and $-1$, but you *can* prove that any eigenvalues must have complex *modulus* $1$, so anything on the complex unit circle.  Rather than $Q^Tx=\lambda x$, we should rather learn that $Q^Tx=\lambda^{-1} x$.

Comment: Maybe the intended statement was that any real eigenvalue of an orthogonal matrix has to be either $1$ or $-1$? Just a guess...

Answer (score 4):

It might be possible that you've mixed up different results?

The **determinant** of an orthogonal matrix is always $\pm 1$:

$${\bf M}^{\top}{\bf M} = {\bf I}$$
$$\det\left({\bf M}^{\top}{\bf M}\right) = \det\left({\bf I}\right)$$
$$\det({\bf M})\det({\bf M}^{\top}) = 1$$
$$\left[\det({\bf M})\right]^2 = 1$$
$$\det({\bf M}) = \pm 1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{rr} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{array} \right]
$$
This is an orthogonal matrix. Its eigenvalues are $e^{\pm i\theta}.$